# ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output. when trying to install dotenv

Tags: python, pip, package, dotenv

I'm trying to install dotenv for my discord bot with `pip3 install dotenv` but it keeps giving me this error:

```
   ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-xmobtpdk/dotenv/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-xmobtpdk/dotenv/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-install-xmobtpdk/dotenv/pip-egg-info
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-xmobtpdk/dotenv/
    Complete output (51 lines):
        ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
         command: /usr/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-wheel-ts7a2idz/distribute/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-wheel-ts7a2idz/distribute/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-vsx7w_h3
             cwd: /tmp/pip-wheel-ts7a2idz/distribute/
        Complete output (15 lines):
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
          File "/tmp/pip-wheel-ts7a2idz/distribute/setuptools/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
            from setuptools.extension import Extension, Library
          File "/tmp/pip-wheel-ts7a2idz/distribute/setuptools/extension.py", line 5, in <module>
            from setuptools.dist import _get_unpatched
          File "/tmp/pip-wheel-ts7a2idz/distribute/setuptools/dist.py", line 7, in <module>
            from setuptools.command.install import install
          File "/tmp/pip-wheel-ts7a2idz/distribute/setuptools/command/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
            from setuptools.command import install_scripts
          File "/tmp/pip-wheel-ts7a2idz/distribute/setuptools/command/install_scripts.py", line 3, in <module>
            from pkg_resources import Distribution, PathMetadata, ensure_directory
          File "/tmp/pip-wheel-ts7a2idz/distribute/pkg_resources.py", line 1518, in <module>
            register_loader_type(importlib_bootstrap.SourceFileLoader, DefaultProvider)
        AttributeError: module 'importlib._bootstrap' has no attribute 'SourceFileLoader'
        ----------------------------------------
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/fanjin/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/installer.py", line 126, in fetch_build_egg
        subprocess.check_call(cmd)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 364, in check_call
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/bin/python3', '-m', 'pip', '--disable-pip-version-check', 'wheel', '--no-deps', '-w', '/tmp/tmpa_3vnder', '--quiet', 'distribute']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
    
    The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-xmobtpdk/dotenv/setup.py", line 13, in <module>
        setup(name='dotenv',
      File "/home/fanjin/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 152, in setup
        _install_setup_requires(attrs)
      File "/home/fanjin/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 147, in _install_setup_requires
        dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
      File "/home/fanjin/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 673, in fetch_build_eggs
        resolved_dists = pkg_resources.working_set.resolve(
      File "/home/fanjin/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 764, in resolve
        dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(
      File "/home/fanjin/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1049, in best_match
        return self.obtain(req, installer)
      File "/home/fanjin/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1061, in obtain
        return installer(requirement)
      File "/home/fanjin/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 732, in fetch_build_egg
        return fetch_build_egg(self, req)
      File "/home/fanjin/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/installer.py", line 128, in fetch_build_egg
        raise DistutilsError(str(e)) from e
    distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Command '['/usr/bin/python3', '-m', 'pip', '--disable-pip-version-check', 'wheel', '--no-deps', '-w', '/tmp/tmpa_3vnder', '--quiet', 'distribute']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

I'm using Linux and I already tried `sudo pip3 install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel` and tried install dotenv again but that didn't work. I also tried `sudo easy_install -U setuptools` but that didn't work either. I also tried installing another module and it worked, but not for dotenv.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Oh it's because the package is called `python-dotenv` not `dotenv`.

Comment: This is dumb, why doesn't it just redirect automatically :|

Comment: When I mistakenly tried `pip3 install dotenv` and confusingly it seemed to *start* working with the message "Downloading dotenv-0.0.5.tar.gz (2.4 kB), Preparing metadata (setup.py)" but then "error: subprocess-exited-with-error". This answer was the solution!